# Upload image to Azure Blob Storage from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage, imageurl

Is it possible to have the `CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync` accept URL for images?
 I am trying to use the LinkedIn basicprofile api to retrieve the picture URL of the user (already have the URL) and I am trying to maybe download then upload the picture to the Azure Blob, like they selected a picture from their computer.

This is how it looks like now:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPhoto", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
      <div class="browseimg">
          <input type="file" class="display-none" name="file" id="files" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
      </div>
 }
 <button class="btn btn-primary width-100p main-bg round-border-bot" id="falseFiles">
       Upload billede
 </button>
```

The method in the controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        if (fileExt.ToLower().EndsWith(".png") 
             || fileExt.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg") 
             || fileExt.ToLower().EndsWith(".gif"))
        {
            var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync()
            await service.Upload(user.Id, file.InputStream);
        }
   }
    return RedirectToAction("Index")
}
```

Comment: No, is not possible, but from what I see you are uploading in form a file not an URL, do you manually download the Images?

Comment: yeah that is the method that takes the file you selected from your PC and uploads it. Somehow it should be possible. I'm going to try putting it in a stream from reading a URL and uploading that stream or something

Comment: I'm creating something simple for you to do that

Comment: looks like webclient worked. You have something better in mind?

Comment: no that's fine, use that one if it's ok for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like all I needed was a simple

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData("https://media.licdn.com/mpr/..."));
```

and then

```
await service.Upload(user.Id, stream);
```

Answer (score 5):

Below method uploads file(URL) to azure cloudblob

NOTE: Input for this method example

> file="http://example.com/abc.jpg" and ImageName="myimage.jpg";

```
public static void UploadImage_URL(string file, string ImageName)
{
    string accountname = "<YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME>";

    string accesskey = "<YOUR_ACCESS_KEY>";

    try
    {

        StorageCredentials creden = new StorageCredentials(accountname, accesskey);

        CloudStorageAccount acc = new CloudStorageAccount(creden, useHttps: true);

        CloudBlobClient client = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer cont = client.GetContainerReference("<YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME>");

        cont.CreateIfNotExists();

        cont.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
        {
            PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob

        });
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(file);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        CloudBlockBlob cblob = cont.GetBlockBlobReference(ImageName);
        cblob.UploadFromStream(inputStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){ ... }

}
```

Comment: deprecated package